# Stop concat removing leading 0

Tags: sql, oracle

Hoping someone can help.

I am attempting to add a `||'m'` to my query but when I add the concat it removes the leading zero.

With out the `||'m'` I get this result:

```
0.00
```

With the concat I get this result for example:

```
.0m
```

edit:
Here is the query:

```
round(MAX(city_longitude),1) - round(MIN(city_longitude),1)||'m'
```

Cheers

Comment: It'd help if you actually posted the sql you are trying to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping the whole `ROUND` statement in a `TO_CHAR` giving it a format mask.

```
TO_CHAR(round(MAX(city_longitude),1) - round(MIN(city_longitude),1), '0.00')||'m'
```

This way you effectively concatenate a string with a string whereas you are currently concatenating a numeric with a string forcing an implicit conversion.

Implicit conversions are usually frowned upon as they can lead to unexpected results.

Oracle says:

> Oracle recommends that you specify explicit conversions, rather than
>   rely on implicit or automatic conversions, for these reasons:
>
> • SQL statements are easier to understand when you use explicit
>   datatype conversion functions.
>
> • Implicit datatype conversion can have a negative impact on
>   performance, especially if the datatype of a column value is converted
>   to that of a constant rather than the other way around.
>
> • Implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs and
>   may not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit
>   conversion from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an
>   unexpected year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
>   parameter.
>
> • Algorithms for implicit conversion are subject to change across
>   software releases and among Oracle products. Behavior of explicit
>   conversions is more predictable.

Number formats are here:
http://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp

Hope it helps...

Comment: No worries, BTW do you need to ROUND both column values before the subtraction? If not it'd be more efficient to simply ROUND the result before then applying the TO_CHAR etc.

Comment: Instead of this part: round(MAX(city_longitude),1) - round(MIN(city_longitude),1) could you not use: ROUND(MAX(city_longitude) - MIN(city_longitude), 1). That would then call the ROUND function once instead of twice for your query.

Comment: Ollie you explanation was good. Thanks will be useful for someone

Comment: You know, once you have the to_char, the entire round is unnecessary!

Comment: Andrew, of course, you are right. With the TO_CHAR specifying the format of the result, you do not need the ROUND function at all. More effeciency savings in the SQL statement.